# How to get a dictionary's data from List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

Consider the following `List of Dictionaries`(retrieved from database):

```
education =  [{
    "schools" : "Nelson Mandela Metropolitan University",
    "studied_from" : new Date("16/1/2012 02:00:00"),
    "studied_to" : new Date("25/1/2055 02:00:00"),
    "qualifications" : "  National Diploma",
    "fields_of_study" : "Industrial engineering"
  }, {
    "schools" : "Massachusetts Institute of Technology",
    "studied_from" : new Date("16/1/2009 02:00:00"),
    "studied_to" : new Date("25/1/2020 02:00:00"),
    "qualifications" : "B Tech",
    "fields_of_study" : "Information Technology"
  }]
```

I am trying to get the data from one `dict` to be returned. 
I have tried the following:

```
   for edu in context.education:
        studied_to.append(edu.studied_to)
        qualification = edu.qualifications
        fields_of_study = edu.fields_of_study
        school = edu.schools
        recent = max(studied_to)
    if recent:
        print recent
        print qualification
        print fields_of_study
```

This is not working as it always returns the data for the data in the last `dict`,
I also tried putting the `if-statement` inside the `for` loop, but this did not work either as then it runs for all entries.

I ultimately want to use these values to generate on an HTML page.

Comment: you already have a proper way of storing data, in which format you want to convert that data. You can directly loop through the list, and get the key and value to generate your html file.

Comment: You can use `education[-1]`

Comment: education[-1] may not always true, if the list is not in order.

Comment: Could you please clearly explain what you need from that list of dictionary, btw what kind of object is this 'new Date("16/1/2012 02:00:00"),'

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use JavaScript syntax in Python.

Comment: @yopy Its a a `datetime` object

Comment: I do apologize for the confusion of the `new Date("25/1/2020 02:00:00")` syntax that seems like JavaScript, I did not think to check it. I copied it as JSON from my database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code unfortunately makes no sense at all. You seem to be appending some variables to lists, and redefining other variables with the latest version, without ever actually returning the dictionary you want.

It seems however that what you're actually after is the dict with the maximum "studied_to" value. So, you should just replace all that code with `max` with a key:

```
most_recent = max(education, key=lambda s: s['studied_to'])
```

(Also, do please try and post valid syntax for the language you're using. The first snippet appears to be Javascript, not Python.)

Comment: I'll accept your answer as it was the most useful to get to the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21237044/2173793), Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to get the data for the most recent education. You should use a variable to hold the most recent date so far and compare that to the entries in your list. See this as a reference:

```py
max_date = None

for edu in education:
    # this line is for initialization
    if max_date is None:
        max_date = edu["studied_to"]

    # check if we have a recent entry at hand
    if max_date <= edu["studied_to"]:
        max_date = edu["studied_to"]  
        qualification = edu["qualifications"]
        fields_of_study = edu["fields_of_study"]

print max_date
print qualification
print fields_of_study
```

Comment: Using the attribute accessor (`.`) on keys of a `dict` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

With some correction of syntax:

```
from operator import itemgetter

from datetime import datetime

education =  [{
    "schools" : "Nelson Mandela Metropolitan University",
    "studied_from" : datetime.strptime("16/1/2012 02:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
    "studied_to" : datetime.strptime("25/1/2055 02:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
    "qualifications" : "  National Diploma",
    "fields_of_study" : "Industrial engineering"
  }, {
    "schools" : "Massachusetts Institute of Technology",
    "studied_from" : datetime.strptime("16/1/2009 02:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
    "studied_to" : datetime.strptime("25/1/2020 02:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
    "qualifications" : "B Tech",
    "fields_of_study" : "Information Technology"
  }]

most_recent = max(education, key=itemgetter('studied_to'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, your answers were really helpful. I took Daniel's answer and modified it:

```
edu = sorted(education, key=lambda studied_to: studied_to)
```

Now I can call `edu[0]` to get the value of the most recent education:

```
>>> edu[0]["studied_to"]
datetime.datetime(2055, 1, 25, 2, 0)
>>> edu[-1]["studied_to"]
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 25, 2, 0)
```

No matter what `ed[0]` will always be the latest education.